# Java: Asking the user for 2 numbers, then printing sum error

Tags: java, input, console, user-input

When I try to run this it gives me an error saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at lsamelson_lab5.LSamelson_Lab5.main(LSamelson_Lab5.java:21)
Java Result: 1
```

Line 21 is the line asking for the first user input.

I'm running Ubuntu, is this because I'm not importing console correctly, or something is wrong with my java files?

```
package lsamelson_lab5;

import java.io.Console;

/**
*
* @author binka
*/
public class LSamelson_Lab5 {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here\
        Console console = System.console();
        String input = console.readLine("Please enter your first number:");
        int newinput = Integer.parseInt(input);
        String input2 = console.readLine("Please enter your second number: ");
        int newinput2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);
        int sum = newinput + newinput2;
        int diff = newinput - newinput2;
        int mult = newinput * newinput2;
        float div = newinput / newinput2;
        System.out.print(sum);
        System.out.print(diff);
        System.out.print(mult);
        System.out.print(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 21 and what input are you providing?

Comment: String input = console.readLine("Please enter your first number:");

Comment: Why not `System.out.print("Please enter your first number:")`?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
System.out.print("Please enter your first number:")
```

instead of

```
String input = console.readLine("Please enter your first number:");
```

[Console::readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is not that you need
Read lines with

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

**EDIT**

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your first number:");
int newinput = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter your second number: ");
int newinput2 = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: But the user's input isn't stored anywhere.

Comment: Ah yes, where do I put that?

Answer (score 2):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) for `java.io.Console`

> If this virtual machine has a console then it is represented by a unique instance of this class which can be obtained by invoking the System.console() method. If no console device is available then an invocation of that method will return **null**.

IDEs such as Eclipse will result in no console being found. However running from a command prompt/*nix shell *usually* provides a console that can be used.

As a workaround for running in environments where a `Console` is not available, [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) can be used.

```
Scanner alernativeInput = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that means.  I'm not using a virtual machine.